# Remote sync directory in C

Tags: c, linux

I have no experience in C, but...

If I wanted to write a program, in C, for a linux system, that would sync a local file/directory to a remote file/directory, *automatically* when the local file/directory is updated; what libraries or built-ins should I look at?

I looked at inotify so far, but I really lack the terminology to search for this without some help.

**Edit**

This is merely an exercise.

Comment: The naive approach I'd take is writing a client-server app - the client would watch for changes and send a diff to the server, and the server would apply the patch on the remote machine. This seems to be easily realized by using the BSD socket API and libdiff, for example.

Comment: You could do that exercise in any language giving you access to the system calls (e.g. Ocaml, Perl, Python, Ruby, C, C++, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inotify`'s the way to go.  Struggle through it, when you get stuck come back and ask more specific questions here.

Here's an example to get you started (excuse the C++ output statements, imagine `printf` instead):

```
void waitfor_activity(const char *path)
{
        const int fd = inotify_init();
        const int wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, path, IN_MODIFY | IN_CLOSE_WRITE);

        char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];
        while (true)
        {
                const ssize_t length = read(fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN); 
                if (length < 0) {
                        perror("read");
                }  
                const struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) buffer;
                std::cout << "event: ";
                if (event->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
                {
                        std::cout << "IN_CLOSE_WRITE ";
                }
                if (event->mask & IN_MODIFY)
                {
                        std::cout << "IN_MODIFY ";
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement.

Answer (score 3):

There is [librsync](http://librsync.sourceforge.net/), a library that implements the rsync algorithm. But do you really need to do this in C? A more common, and much easier way, would be to use shellscripts and the [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) program.

Comment: Yes. I'm very familiar with rsync. This is more or less a training exercise as I'm trying to get familiar with different languages. I'll take a look at librsync.